# Is there any way to validate uniqueness of email on JS in a ruby on rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation

I was wondering if there is any way to validate a uniqueness attribute on JS and then show the error message on the HTML? 
I have already done the backend validations on the model

Comment: You need an ajax request to ask server for the uniqueness check. And show the corresponding message. 
Are you using any front end validation plugin like Parsley or Jquery validation?

Comment: so far I haven't used any front end validation plugins

Comment: Okay let's do it in a pure javascript/jquery way. Let me right an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ajax request to ask server for the uniqueness check. And show the corresponding message.
So add following line at the start of `routes.rb`

`post "/check_email" => "main#check_email" #I am assuming you have "main" controller. other wise replace "main" with your actual controller name`

Then on `keypress` or `change` event of your email input field you need to request server to ask for uniqueness email.

```
$.ajax({url: '/check_email',method: 'POST',
data: {email : 'myemail@email.com'},
success: function(response){
    if(response && response.message=='ERROR'){
        alert("This Email already taken")
    }
}});
```

This script is sending an ajax request to the above route and passing the `email` as parameter. (I am hard coding email here you need to set the appropriate value like `$("#my_email_field").val()`)

Now need to add an `action` in your controller. (in this case in `mainController`)

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def check_email
    email_found = User.where(email: params[:email]).count > 0 #Whatever your logic is to find duplicate emails
    message = email_found ? "ERROR" : "SUCCESS"
    render json: {message: message}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a call to your backend. There should be comparison between what you have as emails and what is being submitted and you only have these data in the backend. 
You could try having a separate contoller with simple logic for fast validations if speed is what you are worried about.